# How get sos morse code from message in android

Tags: android

How convert a message string into morse code & flashes light that present message.Is any library or other way to  doit in android?

Comment: Why don't you code it yourself?  Get each character from the string, get the mappings to an SOS sequence, then have the light turn on and off depending on what the sequence is.

Comment: @BLaZuRE it urgent.for light turn on & off i need only to value.But here gaps spaces,dots.

Comment: I want to understand what you're saying, but I don't.  Yes, Morse code can be explained to be composed of "dots", "dashes", and "spaces".  A "dot" can be a light on for 1 second, a "dash" can be a light on for 2 seconds, and a "space" can be the light off, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this on Google: https://code.google.com/p/morsecoder/ but I'm not sure if it is library; it looks like standalone Java application...

Anyway - coding your own morse code "translator" is very simple - look at this chart on [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code): http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/International_Morse_Code.svg :) The only thing to do is iterate through the single letters and convert them to the morse code. Here you can find some tips: [Morse Code Conversion using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101912/morse-code-conversion-using-java). Then, after converting the letters to the morse code, just turn on/off the flashlight properly - that's all! :)

Comment: according to code there are the character .,-,|. for which character turn on/off flash light.

Comment: Dot means flashlight enabled for short time ("one unit"), dash means flashlight enabled for long time (three units). You should turn off flashlight between parts of the letters (dots and dashes - one unit), between letters (three units) and between words (seven units). That's all :)